# Having newline in alert in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

In my JPS page I am displaying alert using JavaScript and I would like to have new line in the alert message.

EX:

```
Filename has invalid characters:
s
Please try again.
```

This is the code I am using.

```
<%
String validName = "Filename has invalid characters: \n s \n Please try again.";   
out.println("<script>alert('"+validName+"')</script>");
%>
```

However, when this runs, it crashes because the space appear in script:

```
<script>alert('Filename has invalid characters:
s
Please try again.";
```

If I try to escape the new line with \n, then new line does not appear in my alert message. When i use 
 instead, it also does not work.

I also tried this, but the same issue also happen:

```
 <%
 String validName = "Filename has invalid characters: \n s \n Please try again.";   
 %>
 <script>alert('<%=validName%>')</script>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `System.line.separator`

```
<%
String sep = System.line.separator;
String validName = "Filename has invalid characters: " + sep + " s " + sep + " Please try again.";   
out.println("<script>alert('"+validName+"')</script>");
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a few hints here:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-newline

So instead of \n you can try %n or System.lineSeparator()